# Issue with HTML2Canvas - Green overlay while exporting

Tags: angular, chart.js, html2canvas

I'm displaying a chartjs chart in a bootstrap card with other information and exporting the card using html2canvas to image. The exported image has a weird greenish overlay as shown in the image.

Is there something I'm missing out on?

```
html2canvas(document.getElementById(image), {
  logging: false,
  allowTaint: false,
}).then(function (canvas) {
  var uri = canvas.toDataURL();
  var link = document.createElement('a');

  if (typeof link.download === 'string') {
    link.href = uri;
    link.download = fileName;

    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
  } else {
    window.open(uri);
  }
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like there is an issue with html2canvas if you try to export a div with box-shadow. In my case the div has:

```
box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.14) 0 4px 20px 0, rgba(76,175,80,0.4) 0 7px 10px -5px;
```

So, I wrapped my `div` inside another `div` which has no `box-shadow` and also set the background of `card-body` to `white` explicitly.

Comment: Thanks so much for sharing this! I spent *way* too much time trying to figure this out, I would never have thought it was caused by the `box-shadow` property (although it is indeed listed as incompatible in their [documentation](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/features)). Wrapping it did the trick for me too.

Comment: div inside div with box-shadow really helps but not fully, unfortunately...

Answer (score 0):

Not directly answering your question, but offering an alternative: Chart.js provides a native method  - [`.toBase64Image()`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/api.html?h=image#tobase64image) - for generating a data URL in PNG format.

Here's a working example using your code to download a copy of the image via button click:

```js
let canvas = new Chart(document.getElementById("chart"), {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["a", "b"],
    datasets: [{
      label: "series1",
      data: [1, 2]
    }]
  }
});

document.getElementById("download").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var uri = canvas.toBase64Image(); // <-- use ChartJS native method.
  var link = document.createElement('a');

  if (typeof link.download === 'string') {
    link.href = uri;
    link.download = "filename.png"; //fileName;

    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
  } else {
    window.open(uri);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<button id="download">download</button>
<canvas id="chart"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need do convert other parts of the page like title as image as well.